# sqlite using LIKE and hebrew

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to use SQLITE  and the `like` statement with wildcards and hebrew

when I put in an english string it works correctly, such as

```
Select  * from dbname where colname like '%123%'
```

I will get all the entries from that column that contain 123 anywhere in the column.

However if I substitute 123 with hebrew letters - it matches all the entries, not just the ones containing what I asked for.

If I do not use the wilcards in the `like` it matches the exact word properly. In version 3.2.2 of sqlite this worked fine (with wildcards), later versions it does not. So for example "SELECT * from dbname where colname like `'%אב%'` will give me all the entries not only the ones matching אב.

I tried GLOB, which also did not work.